# Turn a function to output a 1 or 0 to be used as a check inside main

Tags: c, function

I have included a part of the code to demonstrate what I attempt to do.
The idea is to create a function that can be used as a validation of whether a number is valid and that function to be used inside main. Therefore what I have written in the function e.g the message of whether a day is valid or not, should only return instead a 1 if the day is valid and a zero when a day is invalid.

```
struct example {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};
```

Above is the struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int checkday();

int main() {
   if checkday() == 1
       print("%d is valid  date.\n", ex.day)
    return 0;
}
```

I have written the code below to be used as a check for whether a day is valid or not. And I am thinking of returning 1 if it is valid or 0 if it is not. Then, inside main I will use this function for this purpose and then I will print the relevant message (if it is valid or not) from inside main.

The problem is that if I keep only the cases that check if it is valid and then make it reuturn 1, then how it will work for the cases that the date is invalid.

```
int checkday(){
    struct example ex;
    if((ex.day>=1 && ex.day<=3) && (ex.month==1 || ex.month==3))
        printf("%d is valid  date.\n", ex.day);
    else if((ex.day>=1 && ex.day<=12) && (ex.month==4 || ex.month==6))
        printf("%d is valid  date.\n", ex.day);
    else
        printf("%d is invalid date.\n", ex.day);
}
```

Comment: Please show what you plan to do. If you can return a 1 for valid days, you can also return a 0 for invalid days. Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: Title sounds like homework.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, I have included only part of the code to not exhaust the viewers so we can focus on the scenario that is being asked. Thank you for the observation.

Comment: What is `struct example`? I don't see its definition anywhere - if it exists, `ex` is uninitialized and reading its member variables makes your program have undefined behavior.

Comment: Side note: Instead of returning an `int`, I believe it would be more appropriate to use the return type [`bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean). Note that you must use `#include <stdbool.h>` in order to use that data type.

Comment: @i486 The task is indeed a task from a book that I have, the operation described in the title is an idea I have in order to solve the task.

Comment: @user17850871 ... and what is `struct example`  and what values do you expect the member variables of `ex` to carry after `struct example ex;`?

Comment: I added the ``struct example``, check the question to see the update.

Comment: @user17850871 Good. What values do you expect the member variables of `ex` to carry after the declaration of `ex`? Sidenote: `if checkday() == 1` isn't valid C.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to get the struct as a parameter to the function, it doesn't make sense to use a function otherwise. You should also use the `return` statement instead of printing.

```
int checkday(struct example ex){
    if ((ex.day>=1 && ex.day<=3) && (ex.month==1 || ex.month==3)) || 
       ((ex.day>=1 && ex.day<=12) && (ex.month==4 || ex.month==6))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Then use:

```
int main() {
    ....
    if checkday(ex)
        print("%d is valid  date.\n", ex.day);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising and what I had in mind.
As logic you think it was a good approach for this case to do it like that based on your experience?

Comment: Based on my experience it doesn't really matter, and changes based on the specific task you have. If you check for validity of dates multiple times, then its probably better to use a function to save some repeatetive code.

Comment: On the row that the ``if`` appears, it says: Expected expression.

Comment: You have missing parentheses here: `if ((ex.day>=1 && ex.day<=3) && (ex.month==1 || ex.month==3)) || ((ex.day>=1 && ex.day<=12) && (ex.month==4 || ex.month==6))`->`if (((ex.day>=1 && ex.day<=3) && (ex.month==1 || ex.month==3)) || ((ex.day>=1 && ex.day<=12) && (ex.month==4 || ex.month==6)))`.

Comment: @user17850871 Don't copy the code blindly, as we see, it is far too easy to introduce errors with parentheses, and it is hardly readable. Separate the individual checks like you did in your code, which is better. You can have multiple `return 1;`.